# Auto resize "div" when another is added

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a video portal using `WebRTC` and need to have the child divs resize when a new member has joined a chat. If 1 person is in a chat I need the their div to be 100% height and width. If a second joins I need both divs to be 50%; a third 33% and so on. How can I accomplish this? The div element are being created within js.

Edit: Added current code.

videoportal.htm

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Video Portal</title>
        <script src="js/simplewebrtc.bundle.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/videoportal.js"></script>
        <style type="Text/CSS">
            @import url('css/style.css');
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="backbutton"><a href="javascript:window.history.back();" style="border:0px;"><img src="images/back.png" class="backimg"></a></div>
        <div id="remotes">
        </div>
        <div class="mainlocal">
            <video id="localVideo"></video>
        </div>
        <div class="logo"><a href="https://video.landrethlans.com" style="border:0px;"><img class="logoimg" src="images/logo.png"></a></div>
        <div class="controlbar">
            <a href="javascript:togglemute();" style="border:0px;"><img class="muteimg" id="muteimg" src="images/mute.png"></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
.mainremote {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:table   }

.backbutton {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 25px;
    left: 10px; }

.backimg {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px; }

.mainlocal {
    position: absolute;
    height:19%;
    width: 12%;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    z-index:100; }

.mainlocal video {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px; 
    overflow: hidden; }

.videoContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto; }

.videoContainer video {
    flex: 1; 
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; }

.backbutton {
    padding-left: 10px; }

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 20px; 
    height:50px;
    width:100px;}

.logoimg {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;}

.controlbar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
}

.muteimg {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px; }

body {
    background-color: #0f0f0f;
}
```

videoportal.js

```
var room = location.search && location.search.split('?')[1];
var tggle;


function setRoom(name) {
    document.title = "Video room: " + room;
}

if (room) {
    setRoom(room);
} else {
    window.location = "url";
}

var webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
    localVideoEl: 'localVideo',
    remoteVideosEl: '', // empty string
    autoRequestMedia: true,
    url: 'URL'
});

// we have to wait until it's ready
webrtc.on('readyToCall', function () {
    // you can name it anything
    webrtc.joinRoom(room);
});

webrtc.on('videoAdded', function (video, peer) {
    console.log('video added', peer);
    var remotes = document.getElementById('remotes');
    if (remotes) {

        // create video container
        var container = document.createElement('div');
        container.className = 'videoContainer';
        container.id = 'container_' + webrtc.getDomId(peer);
        video.className = 'remvideo';
        container.appendChild(video);

        // suppress contextmenu
        video.oncontextmenu = function () { return false; };

        remotes.appendChild(container);
    }   
});

webrtc.on('videoRemoved', function (video, peer) {
    console.log('video removed ', peer);
    var remotes = document.getElementById('remotes');
    var el = document.getElementById(peer ? 'container_' + webrtc.getDomId(peer) : 'localScreenContainer');
    if (remotes && el) {
        remotes.removeChild(el);
    }
});

// local volume has changed
webrtc.on('volumeChange', function (volume, treshold) {
    showVolume(document.getElementById('localVolume'), volume);
});

// remote volume has changed
webrtc.on('remoteVolumeChange', function (peer, volume) {
    showVolume(document.getElementById('volume_' + peer.id), volume);
});

function togglemute(){
    if(tggle=='on'){
        document.getElementById('muteimg').src="images/mute.png";
        tggle='off';
        webrtc.unmute();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('muteimg').src="images/unmute.png";
        tggle='on';
        webrtc.mute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we have more information to what you have tried?

Comment: Honestly I'm having trouble figuring out where to start. I've defined the height width in css. I've only tried display: flex.

Comment: I want them displaying horizontally.

Comment: use `display:table` check answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to work with a horizontal list and edit this list according to what you want to place in it.

As you can see from the following code adding or removing `li` elements those elements will always be even spaced out.

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch; /* Default */
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    background: #cacaca;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    flex: 0 1 auto; /* Default */
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #fafafa;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Member 1</li>
    <li>Member 2</li>
    <li>Member 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is displaying them vertically still. I've posted my code above as a reference.

Comment: I can see the snippet and it shows the members horizontally, to what are you referring that it shows them vertically?

Comment: I'm a dummy, I wasn't using unordered list.

Comment: This is working if I don't give the video container or video height or width of 100%. If I don't give them height/width they are not properly sized.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Table` element and set its `id="myTable"`, then apply the Javascript snippet to add new row dynamically like shown below;

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

// Create an empty <tr> element
var row = table.insertRow(0);

// Insert new cells (<td> elements)
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

// set context
cell1.innerHTML = "YOUR CONTENT";
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: Essentially you are adding CONTENT to the data table, so it's more like a dynamic data processing (not just layout) and Tables are the right tools for that. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Here you go sample with jQuery. Works well, but could be improved, like setting the height of old users before adding new one and that new one append with preset height instead of appending without height care and than loop.

```js
function addUser(){
var count = $(".container .user").length; 
//get num of users

var newColor = '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6); 
//get rand color - for demonstration purposes of this demo

var height = 100/(count+1);
/*calculate height of each user after adding the new one (the new one is the +1)*/
/*also you may want to limit this, so the user divs will not be extra small*/
if(height<=10){height=10; $(".container").css("overflow-y","scroll")}

$(".container").append("<div class='user' style='background:"+newColor+"'></div>");
/*append new div*/

$(".container .user").css("height",height+"%"
);
/*loop through users div and set correct height*/
}
```

```css
.container{
width:150px;
height:200px;
border:1px solid black;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:120px;


}
.user{width:100%; position:relative; margin:0; float:left;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="addUser();">Add user</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to make the container flexible for different aspect ratios.

Comment: well, you can, in this demo, user div has 100% width and height is divided into container height with limit of 10%. You can change this at any time or add logic for dynamic resizing